# Getting current logged on user in web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am trying to retrieve the current logged on user details in a Web API controller to create a user profile page.

I have got the method created but the user keeps returning null in the code was shown below. This works fine in my MVC controller but in Web API controller it throws an error.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult userProfile()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = _userManager.Users.First(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name);
        return Ok(new UserViewModel
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            UserName = user.Email,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Client, Administrator")]
public IActionResult userProfile()
{

    string baseUrl = "https://localhost:5001";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", HttpContext.Session.GetString("token"));

    UserViewModel userModel = new UserViewModel();
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/UserAPI").Result;
    string stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    userModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserViewModel>(stringData);

    return View(userModel);
}
```

Error Message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements

Comment: What are you passing when you call your API?

Comment: @SimonPrice please see my updated question of my Get Method in the MVC Controller

Answer (score 1):

An API is stateless meaning that there is no concept of logged in users or sessions. This is because each request is unique, separate and holds all the information required to provide a response.

An API has no way of knowing who is sending a request, there can be 10k people all sending requests at the same time, so who exactly is "logged in"?

So, if you want to load a user profile then send the userID as a parameter, something like:

```
    [HttpGet]

    public IActionResult userProfile(string userEmail)
    {
         if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty (userEmail) ) ..... etc etc
         {
            var user = _userManager.Users.First(x => x.Email == userEmail);
            return Ok(new UserViewModel
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                UserName = user.Email,
                FirstName = user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName
            });   
        }
    }
```

As a side note, if you don't have any input parameters or the input is a primitive type such as string or int, then ModelState.IsValid won't do anything. Only use ModelState.IsValid if you have a model class populated with the right rules.

in my case I could actually replace the string with a class

```
public class UserProfileRetrieveModel
{
      [Required]
      public string UserEmail { get;set; }
}
```

then I can do :

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult userProfile(UserProfileRetrieveModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = _userManager.Users.First(x => x.Email == model.UserEmail);
            //etc
        }
        else
        {

            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        }
    }
```

--- after question updated

so it looks like you have a client application and from that you call the API.
everything I said above still applies, simply populate the data you have before calling the API.

Example:

```
public IActionResult userProfile()
{
//removed code we don't care about

   string userEmail = "";// get your user email here in the MVC controller
   //populate it in the api url.
   //you might need to URL encode it since it will contain dots and @

   string apiUrl = "https://localhost:5001/api/UserAPI/{userEmail}";
   HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;        
}
```

you don't need to work out anything in the API, just pass everything you need to the API, from the MVC controller.

Now, all this aside, you have massive async issues. that part needs work although it's not related to the question.

Comment: This works for the Post method but doesnt for the get method as I am looking to populate the input form with details of the user logged in

Comment: that doesn't change anything, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Im presuming you're on WebAPI 2.

Try the following:

```
var user = _userManager.GetUser(HttpContext.User);
```

or

```
var user = _userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: I have using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity; in the class but still isnt picking it up. I have also tried RequestContext.Principal but it can't find it,

Comment: @LouiseFinch You're on .NET Core. Try the updated answer

Comment: @LouiseFinch What does `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();` return?

Comment: it says HttpContext does contain the definition Current

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .First() change it to .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Check your condition is right or wrong.
 User.Identity.Name has value

Answer (score 0):

From the error message It seems you are trying to retrieve an element from an empty sequence. So check whether you have the the data or not.And also try to use .FirstOrDefault().